# Is this Syllogism Valid?

Tags: logic

> All widgets are round.
> All widgets are smooth.
> Therefore, some smooth things are round.

My intuitive answer is **YES**.

The provided answer is "NO". Please explain.

### Why I think the answer is "YES".

[image]

Comment: maybe explain why you think it's valid.

Comment: Maybe there are no widgets.

Comment: Your diagrams imply that either all round things are smooth or all smooth things are round which is does not follow from the assumptions. You should've drawn the widget circle in the intersection of the round and smooth circles, and remember that the intersection might as well be empty.

Comment: True, I made a mistake there.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly why Venn diagrams have an advantage!

Start with a basic 3-set Venn diagram:

[image]

Take the first premise:

> All widgets are round

This means that there cannot be any widgets that are not round. So, we shade the area inside Widget and outside Round, which is our way of saying: "there is nothing here":

[image]

Take the second premise:

> All widgets are smooth

This has the same logical form as the previous claim, so shade the appropriate area:

[image]

OK, the conclusion is:

> Some smooth things are round

OK, for there to be smooth things that are round, we need something in the intersection of Smooth and Round.  Let's see if there is something there:

[image]

No, we can't say that there is definitely something there, since the areas are 'blank', and a 'blank' area means that there *could* be something there, but you don't know (as a mnemonic: you 'draw a blank'!). So, the conclusion is not necessarily true. Hence, the argument is invalid.

Now, if you *knew* that there *are* widgets (if, for example, you make the Assumption off Categorical Existential Import, which says that for any class/set/category of objects, there is always one element/member ... an assumption logic *typically* does *not* make ... but if you do:), then there is only one place for those widgets to be:

[image]

(The 'X' means: there is at least one thing here')

And now of course the argument *would* follow.  As such, this kind of argument is sometimes called 'conditionally valid'. But unconditionally, it is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the succinct explanation.